# How many dependent transactions will Infura accept?

Tags: transactions, infura, pending-transactions

How can I reliably send many TXs simultaneously on mainnet with Infura?

I'm trying to send a lot of TXs at once (like one hundred).

I've been able to do this on Goerli (getting in 120+ TXs in one block) by specifying the nonce immediately when sending them.

I've heard that trying to do this on Mainnet isn't reliable, because the node you're connected to might only receive a small number of dependent transactions (ie those with nonces higher than the current nonce).

But given that it works in Rinkeby (using Infura), wondering whether this is likely to work on mainnet (also using Infura)?

It's expensive to test, which is why I ask.

Comment: I think it is 100k transactions per day for free tier account.